# Azure AD not redirecting to the original request url rather goes back to Root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP .Net MVC5 application using Azure AD Authentication. Whenever I enter URL, it takes me for authentication (if not done already) using a URL of this sort.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantID]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BtenantID%5D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)?

There are 3 questions

1. Can I say its using OAuth2 ?
2. If someone enters a url for a page e.g. https://mydomain/Category/View/1, then it goes for auth (which is alright), but then post successful authentication, it should redirect me to the originally requested URL but currently its taking me to the root URL https://mydomain . But subsequent ones, work fine once authenticated.
3. Currently the auth happens every 1 hr I believe..how can I extend  it to every 4 hrs ?

Will be helpful to see your suggestions.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description of point 2, would you like to achieve that, visiting a url -> direct to login page -> redirect to that url? If so, I think [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris) can help you.

In my opinion, if I wanna a demo app or app just for simple test, just add all possible url to the redirect configuration form. If I need to do an formal app or I need to make it easy to maintain, I use the idea in the above document. I think the centeral thought is `creating a specific place to control url redirecting, including judgment, and only need to add this specific url to the redirect configuration in azure portal`. If you wanna a sample, may [this document](https://joonasw.net/view/avoiding-wildcard-reply-urls-with-msal-js) will help you.

To point 3, emmm perhaps you can search for some key words like 'azure ad authentication set token lifetime policy', I found several powershell scripts but I haven't tested. If you haven't got the result I will do some test on it next Monday.

Comment: Regarding the question #2,  As of 2023, ReturnURL should automatically work if standard Azure Identity is applied following the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-web-app-aspnet-sign-in